# Vertical Position of One of Two Legends in ggplot2 graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to control the position of one relative to the other in a ggplot created graphic with two legends?

In the simple graphic below,  I'm trying to vertically align the legend key for "Normal" with the "Some color" legend key. I'd like the red line to be the same height on the graphic as the center of color bar.

The first image below is where I'm stuck. The 2nd image below is the desired result, if a single legend can be moved.

A reproducable example is provided below. In this case, the title of the "Normal" legend is blank and I'm using the label only.   I tried using label.vjust=0.5 (or 1) option in the legend_guide but it's a small vertical move and the red line does not move with it.

[image: my attempt]

[image: my desired result]

An example:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr)

tt <- tibble(a=runif(15))
tt <- tt %>% mutate(n=row_number())

tt %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_col( aes(x=n,y=a,fill=a)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=n,y=a,color='Normal'),size=1) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('Normal'='red')) + 
  labs(title='A Title',
       x='Some Numbers',
       y='The Y-Axis',
       color = '',
       fill='Some Color') + 
  theme(plot.title   = element_text(hjust=0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(size=13,face='bold'),
        legend.text  = element_text(size=13,face='bold'),
        legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key.width=unit(1.0,"cm"),
        legend.key.height=unit(.25,"cm"),
        legend.box.background = element_blank(),
        legend.justification = "center",
        legend.margin = margin(0.,0.,0.,0., unit="cm"),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0, 0, 0, "cm")) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title.position = "top",
                               title.hjust = 0.5),
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "top", 
                              label.vjust = 0.5, #centres the title horizontally
                              label.position = "top",
                              order=1)
                              )
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How about leaving the label blank and instead using the label as title? Would that be an option?

Comment: It's an option but then there is a substantial gap between the title and the line.  The title is placed above the label.   What I'm hoping to find out is how to align the red line in the legend with the color bar.  So, somehow that red line needs to move up while the label (or title) remains above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a hack, but if you wanna fine tune plots like this, I guess there's hardly any other way (or you make a fake legend).

Assign value " " (space!) to your aesthetic and map the color to this. Thus, the legend won't have a visible label and you can place it "bottom".

<sup>P.S you should always `set.seed` before running sampling functions.</sup>

```r
library(tidyverse)
tt <- tibble(a=runif(15))
tt <- tt %>% mutate(n=row_number())

data.frame()
#> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
tt %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_col( aes(x=n,y=a,fill=a)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=n,y=a, color = " "), size=1) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title='A Title',
       x='Some Numbers',
       y='The Y-Axis',
       fill='Some Color', 
       color = "Normal") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(' '='red'))+
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title.position = "top",
                               title.hjust = 0.5),
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "top", 
                              label.vjust = 0.5, #centres the title horizontally
                              label.position = "bottom",
                              order=1)
  )
```

[image]

Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)

Comment: That worked!  Thanks for helping.